# Sort dataframe based on minimum value of two columns

Tags: python, pandas

Let's assume I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4], 'col2': [4, 2, 1, 3], 'col3': [1,0,1,1], 'outcome': [1,0,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

I want this dataframe sorted by col1 and col2 on the minimum value. The order of the indexes should be 2, 0, 1, 3.

I tried this with `df.sort_values(by=['col2', 'col1'])`, but than it takes the minimum of col1 first and then of col2. Is there anyway to order by taking the minimum of two columns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`numpy.lexsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lexsort.html):

```
order = np.lexsort(np.sort(df[['col1', 'col2']])[:, ::-1].T)

out = df.iloc[order]
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  outcome
2     3     1     1        1
0     1     4     1        1
1     2     2     0        0
3     4     3     1        0
```

Note that you can easily handle any number of columns:

```
df.iloc[np.lexsort(np.sort(df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3']])[:, ::-1].T)]

   col1  col2  col3  outcome
1     2     2     0        0
2     3     1     1        1
0     1     4     1        1
3     4     3     1        0
```

Answer (score 2):

One way (not the most efficient):

```
idx = df[['col2', 'col1']].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), axis=1).sort_values().index
```

Output:

```
>>> df.loc[idx]
   col1  col2  col3  outcome
2     3     1     1        1
0     1     4     1        1
1     2     2     0        0
3     4     3     1        0

>>> idx
Int64Index([2, 0, 1, 3], dtype='int64')
```

Answer (score 2):

you can [decorate-sort-undecorate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) where decoration is minimal and other (i.e., maximal) values per row:

```py
cols = ["col1", "col2"]
(df.assign(_min=df[cols].min(axis=1), _other=df[cols].max(axis=1))
   .sort_values(["_min", "_other"])
   .drop(columns=["_min", "_other"]))
```

to get

```py
   col1  col2  col3  outcome
2     3     1     1        1
0     1     4     1        1
1     2     2     0        0
3     4     3     1        0
```

Answer (score 1):

I would compute min(col1, col2) as new column and then sort by it

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,4], 'col2': [4, 2, 1, 3], 'col3': [1,0,1,1], 'outcome': [1,0,1,0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df['colmin'] = df[['col1','col2']].min(axis=1) # compute min
df = df.sort_values(by='colmin').drop(columns='colmin') # sort then drop min
print(df)
```

gives output

```
   col1  col2  col3  outcome
0     1     4     1        1
2     3     1     1        1
1     2     2     0        0
3     4     3     1        0
```